# Auto-review is very confusing

Tags: bug, quality-improvement

In a rare step today, to try to find out what the company is trying to do with less community and more autoreview, I asked a new question on SO main. 
I entered a specific title. well-formatted body, and appropriate tags.  I checked again for duplicates.  I clicked Post Your Question, and nothing seemed to happen.

I scrolled up and down the page looking for something called out as an error, and couldn't find any.   Still confused, I kept searching, and then found this in the right sidebar:

[image: Your question is ready to publish!]

If the question is ready to publish, can clicking "Post Your Question" just go ahead and do that, instead of requiring the confusing extra step?

Comment: But the button doesn't say "Post your question" when you first click it, it says ["**Review** your question"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puXOG.png)